# Exchanging Canadian dollars for Pound Sterling

Tags: money, canada, uk, exchange

Could you tell me how many pounds sterling I would receive from you for 1,680 CA dollars?

Comment: From *us*? You may have been mistaken; this site does not provide currency exchange services. Anyway, the [Universal Currency Converter](http://www.xe.com/ucc/convert/?Amount=1680&From=CAD&To=GBP) is an excellent tool for such conversions.

Comment: There are many such tools. I usually use a site called coinmill but for quick checks you can type straight into Google as Roflcopter points out in his answer.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Travel.SE. The question you've asked it WAY too specific as currency exchange rates fluctuate all the time. You're better off using Google's built-in converter as listed below or a website like www.coinmill.com. I do hope you stick around our website and feel free to ask other questions you have related to travel!

Comment: You could reformulate your question and ask more general how to get the actual exchange rate.

Answer (score 6):

Enter

```
1,680 CAD in GBP
```

in [Google](http://www.google.ch/search?q=1,680%20CAD%20in%20BPS&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#pq=1,680%20cad%20in%20bps&hl=de&sugexp=gsis,i18n=true&cp=16&gs_id=x&xhr=t&q=1,680%20CAD%20in%20GBP&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&client=firefox-a&hs=hYo&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=1,680%20CAD%20in%20GBP&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=5a959ab830609a8d&biw=2560&bih=1332). In newer version of Firefox you don't even have to navigate to Google first but you can directly enter it in the address bar.

Then you get the actual exchange rate. So actually you get 1,0736.1917 Pound Sterling

If you're talking about 1680 CAD then you have to adapt the query properly.

Comment: Since Veryan provided three digits after the comma, I am guessing the comma was meant to be a [digit grouping delimiter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Digit_grouping) as opposed to a [decimal mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark).  Therefore, CAD$1680 ≈ £1074.